# How to get myshopify custom page content from server

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I have created the my custom page called "pages.api.main-menu.liquid"

When I access page from preview mode it shows the the content.
[image: accessed via browser]

The case is I want to take the content of this page from Next Server. So I sent a request directly to this page.

```
export default (req, res) => {
  const {
    SHOPIFY_STORE_URL,
    SHOPIFY_ADMIN_API_KEY,
    SHOPIFY_ADMIN_API_PASSWORD
  } = process.env
  
  serverCoreAPI
    .get(
      `https://${SHOPIFY_ADMIN_API_KEY}:${SHOPIFY_ADMIN_API_PASSWORD}@${SHOPIFY_STORE_URL}/pages/main-menu-api`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      res.status(200).send(response.data || { data: null })
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}
```

I am taking as a response the error code 400.
Anyone can help with this?

Comment: You shouldn't need the API Key or Password if you're accessing the storefront.  Just use the URL you used in your screenshot.  (And please don't use images to take pictures of text).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to access it via storefront with token in the response header, instead I am taking 403. This is because store is protected. Any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried unprotecting the store?
You can also use the API: GET /admin/api/2021-04/pages.json?handle=main-menu-api

Comment: Unprotecting the store works fine. No 403 error there. However, I am looking for workaround with enabled protection. Getting pages.json doesn't give body of the page, only content of the page, which is inserted from shopify dashboard. I need compiled liquid code there...

Comment: To get around the protection you'll need to provide the password, which should set a cookie which you can pass to the page request.  I tried it by copying the cookie from my browser, and that worked at least for the moment.  Or you can POST to the enter password form.